# Is it possible tracking shape changes in powerpoint addin?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-addins

Currently on my project of ppt addin, I want to know if it is possible tracking shape changes made by the user:

- Text Box A Move to ( 210, 100)
- Text Box B Change Font to Calibri
- Text Box B Change Style to Underline
- Delete Text Box C
- Add Image A
- Resize Image A to 320x240
- ...

What I know for PPT 2013 there's an `AfterShapeSizeChange` event so you can know after re-sizing, but I need more than that, which is all possible changes did by the user.

After trying to find out through browsing, here's some possibilities:

1. Create my own log tracking using SelectionChanged event, but this gonna be tricky if user press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
2. look through undo/redo stack (people says it's impossible...)

Comment: In Microsoft Word, there's a feature called "Track Changes" where user can accept or reject the changes made before. In Powerpoint, there's no such feature. I'm wondering if we can somehow know which buttons in ribbon is pressed, e.g. detect when user push bold, change font size value, change alignment, etc.

Comment: There's no way to know which buttons were pressed, but you could, at least in theory, hide the existing ribbon UI and replace it with your own identical-looking copies.  Having done that (again, theory) your "faux" UI could call your own routines that first do whatever's needed to record changes and then call the original button (via ExecuteMso, I think it's called).  Can't say as I'd really want to do this. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to actually track changes or do you need to be able to detect that a change has been made?  Ie, that a given shape isn't exactly the same as it was in the original.

If the latter, how about this:

Write a routine that "touches" each shape in the presentation and adds tags to it, one tag for each property that you want to be able to detect changes to.

Then all you'd need to do is look at each shape's tags and see if the properties stored there match the current properties of the shape.

For example, to tag the shapes:

```
For each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slides
  For each oSh in oSl.Shapes
    oSh.Tags.Add "Left", cstr(oSh.Left)
    oSh.Tags.Add "Top", cstr(oSh.Top)
  Next
Next
```

Comment: yep, seems you're right so right now i'm creating a kind of "activity watcher" by keep looking on keyboard and mouse activity.
does the user do mouse clicking? or press a button? does the user press ctrl+z? based on these events i will compare the shape's last state with the current state.  
i think this might work :)
thanks :)

Comment: tried to implement Keyboard Hook (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) and Mouse Hook (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx). It's a keyboard and mouse detection in the low level. Crap, for keyboard hook it doesn't work for office 2013 :(
really need this keyboard hook for CTRL+Z/CTRL+Y detection :(

Comment: after a week my system can detect selectionchanged event and mousehook, i trigger an event when the mouse is up (for example mouse up after dragging or change the font style...) i found out that after mouse up event the shape attributes isn't updated afterwards. then i use System.Windows.Forms.Timer to detect changes in my slide, so far it runs quite good, one issue remain is choosing which update should be inside timer, which update should be detected during selectionchanged otherwise all load will be inside timer and it's going to be really slow :)

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem.

Let me say, I think the best solution would be serialize the shape to XML (shape state) and save it in the shape it-self. In this way next time you access the shape you can check the current state with the serialized one.

It's possible to save XML in a shape, but you cannot serialize the COM shape in "one command", you have implement your own serialization looking to all shapes properties (!!!! to much I think).

What I did as work-around is: every time the user puts a shape (let's say ShapeA) in the slide a create a shape copy in a specific master page (ShapeA_state1), the new shape holds my ShapeA state. Then I save a reference to that ShapeA_state1 into the ShapeA. In this way when a second time the app access the ShapeA, the app can check if the state is changed looking to the referenced ShapeA_state1. When that happens, ShapeA.1 is updated to ShapeA_edited

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to add a thread to your program that monitors Application.ActivePresentation.Saved - if it gets set to false you know a change has been made and can look at the selected object or slide - of course you need to add a layer to reset the Saved flag - and pass it back before saving.

I've had no success with accessing the undo information.

I have had good success with adding a mouse hook and intercepting button presses before PPT does - perfect for intercepting things like the PlaySlideShow button before Application_SlideShowBegin and the Next/Prev slides during playback before Application_SlideShowNext* events.

When working out where the button positions you wish to intercept are keep in mind things such as PresenterMode and DPI scale changes.